# JBoss EAP 6.1 Alpha: Is Windows 7 a supported platform?

Tags: java, jboss

I've just downloaded JBoss EAP 6.1 Alpha from JBoss and installed on my Windows 7 machine.

As per JBoss, the [supported/tested platform is: Microsoft Windows 2008 server](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/111663)

Nevertheless, I could successfully create a new user, start the server and log into it's management console as well.

Has anyone done this before without facing issues in the long run, especially when using the Java EE features such as EJB, JTA, WebServices etc.?  In other words, can we use JBoss in development/production without any issues in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this page](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/111663), Windows 2008 Server is the configuration they've fully *tested with*. However, on the same page it says it is supported on

> one of the following Technology Component Kit (TCK) certified
>   implementations and on one of the operating systems supported by that
>   implementation. Red Hat relies on the TCK to validate platform
>   compatibility.

One of those mentioned is Oracle JDK 6/7. So if the environment is supported by Oracle JDK 6/7 and you're using that, you should be covered. [Windows 7 is certainly covered by that](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html).

But don't take my word for it, confirm it from Red Hat to get an official quote.

Also, if you want support for your production usage, you should get a commercial support subscription for it from Red Hat.